# Application of Jensen's Inequality to non-negative integrable function

Tags: real-analysis, jensen-inequality

I am reading  a book, where it uses the following result. Can someone help me to derive the result? I know i have to use Jensen's inequality here, but not sure how to get the final result.
Here is the claim.
If $f$ and $g$  be non-negative and integrable functions with respect to a
measure $\mu$  and $S$ be the region in which $f > 0$ . If$\int_{s} ( f - g ) d\mu \ge 0$, then $\int_{s}f\log\frac{f}{g}d\mu \ge 0$.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Does it say whether $S$ has finite measure?  Also, if $g$ is allowed to take the zero value in $S$, what is the meaning of the ratio under the log?

Comment: It doesn't say anything for finite measure. However, I guess we can assume it to be finite for now.

Comment: I may be completely off the path here, but here is what comes to mind:
$$
f - g = f \left( 1 - {g \over f} \right).
$$
And, if $u$ is small enough $|u| << 1$, then $\log(1 + u) \doteq u$.

Allowing $g$ take zero values, however, is still somewhat problematic.

Comment: Also, perhaps the concavity of $\log$ can be explored to compare $(f - g)$ to $(\log f - \log g)$.

Comment: I was trying this way: $\int_{s}fd\mu \ge $ $\int_{s}gd\mu $. Then taking log on both sides,we get  $log \int_{s}fd\mu \ge log \int_{s}gd\mu $. Also from Jensen inequality, we know $\log \int_{s}fd\mu \ge \int_{s}\log fd\mu$.

Comment: Jensen's inequality applies only on a domain of unit measure.  That's why I asked whether $S$ had finite measure: if it does, we can normalize $\mu$ by $\mu(S)$, so as to meet the premise of Jensen's inequality.  See "Measure-theoretic and probabilistic form" in [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality).

Comment: Ok. Lets assume for this purpose we have finite measure.

Comment: @avs why would you need unit measure for Jensen to hold ?

Comment: @Because Jensen's inequality is, essentially, for convex linear combinations, and the sum of the coefficients in such a combination is 1.  See "Measure-theoretic and probabilistic form" in [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality).

Comment: There is one proof using the logarithmic expansion, i.e. $\log x = (x-1)-(x-1)^2(2y^2)^{-1}$. Now substitute $x$  with $\frac{f}{g}$. Then we get the inequality. However, the author also alludes to the fact that Jensen's inequality can be directly applied to deduce the result.

Comment: where $y \in (1,x)$.

Answer (score 1):

We assume $d\mu$ positive (for Jensen to make sense) and first assume $0<A=\int_{S}fd\mu < \infty$, let $h=\frac{f}{A}, hd\mu=d\nu$ is a unit (positive) measure on $S$.

Then with $u=\frac{g}{f} \ge 0$, Jensen inequality says that

$\int_{S}(h\log{u}) d\mu=\int_{S}(\log{u}) d\nu \le \log{\int_{S}ud\nu}=\log{\int_{S}hud\mu}=\log{\int_{S}\frac{g}{A}d\mu}=\log\frac{\int_{S}gd\mu}{\int_{S}fd\mu} \le \log 1 =0$ which immediately gives the required result since

$\int_{S}(h\log{u}) d\mu=-\frac{1}{A}\int_{S}(f\log{\frac{f}{g}}) d\mu$

In general, decompose $S$ into countable disjoint $\mu$-measurable sets for which the integral of $f$ is finite, apply the above and the countable additivity of the integral (which works since each integral of $f\log \frac{f}{g}$ is positive by the above; technically we would also need to separate the case when $g=0$ on a set of non-zero measure for $\mu$ but that is trivial since then the integral of $f\log \frac{f}{g}$ is positive infinity there and again the above applies...

Comment: Thanks.This is great.

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: Out of curiosity, since i only know some basic measure theory, the way you defined $hd\mu=d\nu$ for $\nu$ measure, does that follow from the definition of a measure or is there any theorem that guarantees the existence of such measure? If you can please guide me , I can look into some books for more details .

Comment: $d\nu=hd\mu$, means that for any $\mu$ measurable  set $E$, $\nu(E)=\int_{E}hd\mu$, and this defines a measure as long as $h$ is positive (or more generally absolutely integrable w.r. $\mu$); when $h$ has integral $1$, $\nu$ is a unit measure and Jensen applies - it is a standard procedure in integral inequalities and corresponds to weights adding to $1$ in the discrete inequalities theorems (where Jensen just expresses the concavity of $\log$)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Does this definition of measure follows from Radon–Nikodym theorem?

Comment: the other way around - defining $d\nu=hd\mu$ as above immediately shows $\nu$ measure; the non-trivial part is countable additivity which follows by monotone convergence when $h\ge 0$ and by dominated convergence when $h$ is not necessarily positive but is absolutely integrable wr $\mu$; $\nu$ has an extra property, namely that its null sets contain the null sets of $\mu$  (from the fact that an integral on a null set is zero); this is called absolute continuity and Radon-Nikodym asserts the converse - any absolutely continuous $\nu$ (w.r to $\mu$) is like that, namely there is an $h$ etc

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me. I would imagine a standard book on measure theory would cover this concepts. Still, any suggestion for good read? Thanks again.

Comment: To be honest, I never found a measure theory book that truly satisfies me - I keep on hand Cohn and Rudin (RC) but many times I find them too general for my interests, so I also keep using the classic book on function theory by Titchmarsh

Comment: @Conrad, I found B. Vulikh's *Brief Course in the Theory of Functions* an unrivaled exposition of measure and integration theory.

Comment: Excellent - will definitely take a look at it